# How to select only one Toggle Switch in Listview?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have a `Listview` which has toggle switches. I want to select only one item in `Listview` with toggle switch. When I select second toggle then first toggle must be de-active again. For example in the picture; When I select Rekorida and then I select `Merchandizing` , `Rekorida` must turn back disable. Every time only one option can be active. Is it possible to do it in Xamarin?

[image: Example listview]

My listView Code :

```
 <ScrollView>
                    <ListView x:Name="ShipListView" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SelectionMode="Single">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>

                                    <Grid Margin="4, 3, 4, 3" Padding="2" BackgroundColor="White">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions HeightRequest="40">
                                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                            <!--<RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>-->
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding ShipName}" TextColor="DeepPink" Grid.Column="0" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Switch  IsToggled="{Binding Selected}" Grid.Column="2" Toggled="OnShipToggled" />
                                    </Grid>

                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </ScrollView>
```

And My function

```
async void OnShipToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        
        checkShipSelected = !checkShipSelected;
        if(checkShipSelected)
        {
            
            ViewCell cell = (sender as Switch).Parent.Parent as ViewCell;

            ParametersMemberShipInformation model = cell.BindingContext as ParametersMemberShipInformation;

            if (model != null)
            {
                selectedMemberShipOid = model.Oid;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        

    }
```

I'm trying get **id** of selected item in listview and I do this successfully. Bu I want users can only select one item at the same time because of nice visuality and not be confused.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a minimal code, your xaml for instance?

Comment: @Cfun I edited my post. You can see my codes.

Comment: if I check "others" or "trade check" or any switch among the four switches, you expect the remaining to be uncheked right?

Comment: Exactly!! That's all I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch your  view model in your code behind file and then filter out the selected toggle and marked rest of them as false

```cs
private YourViewModel MyViewModel { get => BindingContext as YourViewModel; }

if (model != null)
{
 selectedMemberShipOid = model.Oid;
 MyViewModel.ShipListView.Where(x=> x.Oid != 
     selectedMemberShipOid).Foreach(x=> x.Selected = false)
 
}
```

Comment: @Veysel can you tell me the name of the list. which is binding to ListView. You can replace the list name with MyList

Comment: "ShipListView" this is my name of list name. And your way is so logical. I'll try it. Thanks for answering. If it works, I'll accept your answer

Comment: I couldn't solve my problem totally but I can say I almost solved it with your great idea. That's why I'll accept your answer. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. This why it doesnt trigger the event on init when binding.

ViewModel.cs

```
bool hasCompletedLoading = false;
    public bool HasCompletedLoading
    {
        get { return hasCompletedLoading; }
        set { SetProperty(ref hasCompletedLoading, value); }
    }
```

Then I set hasCompletedLoading = True after all the Items has been set.

Text.xaml

```
 private async void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
 {
     if (_viewModel.HasCompletedLoading){
        //To somthing
     }
 }
```